# Cloud9 + meteor + autocomplete?

Tags: autocomplete, meteor, cloud9-ide

IS there an auto-complete for meteor framework in Cloud 9 Online IDE?

Suppose there is no auto-complete for meteor framework in Cloud 9, can you recommend for me any online IDE with meteor framework auto complete and it is free?

Comment: We're working on better Meteor support and autocomplete in Cloud9 right now. Send us an email (support@c9.io) with all the features you'd like to see and we'll try and add them in.